# Notational curiosity

Tags: real-analysis, functions, logic, proof-writing

Consider the following statements:

$\forall x,y$ $(x<y \implies f(x)<f(y))$

and

$\forall x,y$, $x<y$ $\implies$ $f(x)<f(y)$

Are these two statements equivalent? If not, may someone please clarify the difference?

Note that the domain of discourse has been omitted.

Comment: No, "strictly increasing" is not equivalent to "strictly decreasing".

Comment: @TheoBendit I fixed the typo

Comment: Ah, now I see why it's a notational curiosity!

Answer (score 2):

I think both are fine, and can be used interchangeably. Technically speaking, the former is preferable, as it clearly defines the scope of the quantifiers. One could be vaguely concerned that someone might interpret the latter as
$$(\forall x, y, x < y) \implies f(x) < f(y).$$
This interpretation would be absurd, as $x$ and $y$ are not defined in this expression, outside the parentheses, and even if they were in some wider context, then using them as dummy variables inside the parentheses would be an abuse of notation. The only reasonable way to interpret the latter expression is as the former expression.

Similar, but more problematic, issues occur with sigma notation (and similar notations). One could write
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i+1} - x_i$$
or
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (x_{i+1} - x_i)$$
and they would mean the same thing. However, one could get genuinely confused when reading
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i - x,$$
as it could be interepreted as
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - x)$$
or
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right) - x.$$